# Jupyter notebook can't find Q# (Qsharp)

Tags: .net, jupyter-notebook, q#

I am following the directions on the [MS Qsharp page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/install-guide/jupyter?view=qsharp-preview). I have IQsharp installed:

```
$ which dotnet
/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
$ dotnet iqsharp --version
Language kernel: 0.6.1905.301
Jupyter core: 1.1.13141.0
```

and Jupyter installed:

```
$ which jupyter
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/jupyter
```

but when I launch `jupyter notebook` I don't see the option to start a Q# kernel (only Python 3). I've also tried by launching Jupyter out of an Anaconda environment.

My suspicion is I need to change the Jupyter configuration somehow to add the IQ kernel to its `--paths`, but I'm not sure how to do that (or if that is even the right thing to do). Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may have IQ# installed correctly, but not yet registered with Jupyter as a kernel. One way to check is to run `jupyter kernelspec list`, which will show a list of all kernels that Jupyter is aware of. For instance, on my machine, I get a list similar to the following (yours may look a bit different, that's entirely OK):

```
Available kernels:
  python3    C:\Users\<username>\Miniconda3\envs\qsharp\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
  iqsharp    C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels\iqsharp
```

If you don't see `iqsharp` listed, it should work to run `dotnet iqsharp install` for a global installation or `dotnet iqsharp install --user` for a user-specific installation.

Comment: Boom. Yes, that did it, thanks! Accepted the answer!

Comment: @GabrielPerdue: Happy to help, I'm glad that worked!